# Postgresql temporary file: No space left on device, location of temporary files

Tags: postgresql

I am running Postgresql 9.6 on a Windows PC, Data directory on 4TB Data disk, Postgresql software on a SSD of 300 GB. I'm running a large & complex query that results in this error:

```
    ERROR: could not write block 196800198 of temporary file: No space left on                                 device
    SQL state: 53100
```

My question: How can I see on which disk it's writing the temporary files?

I suspect it's writing on my 300 GB SSD instead of my Data disk of 4TB.

I'm not interested in optimizing the query to reduce overhead, I just want to know where it's writing the temp files.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-file-layout.html "Temporary files (for operations such as sorting more data than can fit in memory) are created within PGDATA/base/pgsql_tmp, or within a pgsql_tmp subdirectory of a tablespace directory if a tablespace other than pg_default is specified for them."

Comment: Is changing temp_file_limit from -1 to a maximum a possible solution?

Comment: @Willem was this issue resolved?

Comment: @Akhilesh I don't think it was, for some reason the query was too complex, but the lack of transparancy/background is still the issue. Advise: try to simplify query to prevent writing to disk.

Comment: @Willem Exactly! I am using left outer joins to join multiple tables (mostly by id), but still I am getting around 35k rows to be saved on. Have any specific suggestion for this, would be a great help? Thanks!

Comment: @Akhilesh split up query in multiple steps, instead of one off.