# How to resolve "could not write block of temporary file: No space left on device" in postgresql?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-5, pgadmin-4, php-pgsql

I have local database in postgres. In which single table contains data of "74980435".

When I have tried to execute `SELECT` query it is throwing this error:

> "could not write block 657567 of temporary file: No space left on device".

I am trying to execute select query in Laravel.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52606584/postgresql-temporary-file-no-space-left-on-device-location-of-temporary-files

Answer (score 1):

Your query (which you didn't show) is probably missing a join condition or two, or it tries to sort an enormous amountt of rows or cache an enormous function result or materialize node.

When data don't fit in `work_mem`, PostgreSQL starts putting them into temporary disk files. Your query created enough of those to fill the file system temporarily.

You can set the `temp_file_limit` parameter as a defense, but you should figure out the bug in your query.

Comment: There is no bug into the query because now table contains "133072194" records and I am trying to execute "SELECT COUNT(test) FROM mytable WHERE test = false" but it is taking Execution time: 128320.712 ms

Comment: I already have indexing on test column. Could you please let me know, what I can optimize or change, so my query became faster.

Comment: Certainly not without knowing the query and the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output. But you should open another question for that.